# How do I create a new user account with the Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs-api

How do I create a new user account with the Google Docs API?

Answer (score 1):

If you have google apps for your domain, you can try the [provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#using_the_provisioning_api). If you're talking about regular accounts, there is no way to do so programatically.